# Laravel 5.5 AJAX live data search won't work

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a AJAX search in my **blade files** the **show.blade.php** and I am dislaying a specific user in that show method like this in the
url: **http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/1**

Here is my **route**

```
Route::resource('client', 'ClientController',
        ['as' => 'encoder']);
```

It is a resouce controller that includes the show method to display a specific client.

This is what I did in my **controller**

```
public function show($id, Request $request)
    {
        $client = $this->clientRepository->with(['request' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }])->findWithoutFail($id);

        $keyword = $request->get('keyword');

        if (!$keyword) {
            $client_requests = AnalysisRequest::where('client_id', $client->id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        } else {
            $client_requests = AnalysisRequest::where('client_id', $client->id)
            ->OrWhere('id', 'LIKE', '%keyword%')
            ->OrWhere('sample_descrition', 'LIKE', '%keyword%')
            ->OrWhere('special_instruction', 'LIKE', '%keyword%')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        }

        // dd($client_requests);

        if (empty($client)) {
            Flash::error('Client not found');

            return redirect(route('encoder.client.index'));
        }

        echo view('encoder-dashboard.client.show', compact('client_requests'))
        ->with('client', $client)
        ->render();
    }
```

I have a show function that will display a specific client that the id is being passed as a params in the controller in order to show that specific client. Now I also have a request for that specific client that I want to search with.

This is what I have done in my **AJAX**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.searchbar').on('keyup', function(){
          var text = $('#searchbar').val();
          $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              type:"GET",
              url: '{{ url('encoder/client') }}' + '/' + $('.id_search').val(),
              data: {text: $('.searchbar').val()},
              success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

and in my **show.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group" id="results">
                            <input type="hidden" id="client_id" class="id_search" name="client_id" value="{{ $client->id }}">
                            <input class="form-control searchbar" id="searchbar" name="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                @include('encoder-dashboard.client.request')
```

and finally the **request.blade.php**

```
<!-- The timeline -->
  @if (isset($client_requests) && count($client_requests) > 0)
  @foreach($client_requests as $request)
  <ul class="timeline timeline-inverse">
    <!-- timeline time label -->
    <li class="time-label">
          <span class="bg-red">
            {{ $request->created_at->format('M d, Y') }}
          </span>
    </li>
    <!-- /.timeline-label -->
    <!-- timeline item -->
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-edit bg-blue"></i>

      <div class="timeline-item">
        <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ $request->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>

        <h3 class="timeline-header">Request Code: <a href="{!! route('encoder.analysis-request.show', $request->id) !!}">{{ $request->reference_no() }}</a>
            @if ($request->rushable == 1)
              <p style="color:red">This request is for RUSH!</p>
            @else
            @endif
        </h3>

        <div class="timeline-body">
          Description: <b>{{ $request->sample_description }}</b>
          <br>
          Service Requested: <b>{{ $request->service->description }}</b>
          <br>
          Category Requested: <b>{{ $request->category->name }}</b>
          <br>
          Method Requested: <b>{{ $request->methodology->name }}</b>
          <br>
          Special Instruction: <b>{{ $request->special_instruction }}</b>
          <br>
          @if ($request->status == 'for_testing')
              Status: <span class="label label-warning">Pending</span>
          @elseif ($request->status == 'under_analyzation')
              Status: <span class="label label-info">Under Analyzation</span>
          @elseif ($request->status == 'finished')
              Status: <span class="label label-success">Finished</span>
          @endif
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{!! route('encoder.analysis-request.show', $request->id) !!}">Read more</a>
          {{--  <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>  --}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  @endforeach
  @endif
```

I am doing something wrong? I didn't receive any errors in here right now.

I have an **500 internal server error** earlier but manage to fix it because of just a wrong url.

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/encoder/client/1?keyword=dsa 500 (Internal
>   Server Error) send @ jquery.min.js:4 ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
>   (anonymous) @ 1:363 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3 q.handle @
>   jquery.min.js:3

I had my **csrf token** in my meta in the **app.blade.php** and the script ajax setup headers.

Will I create a separate method in the controller that has a same **GET** request with no parameters being passed? and passed the id as an request input hidden for alternative purposes.

Maybe I should do I **POST request** instead of a **GET request?** But How? because I am also displaying a specific resource passing the id as a params.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct url `{{ url('encoder/client') }}` in your AJAX call? From your route, it looks like it should be `{{ url('encoder') }}`

Comment: remove the `['as' => 'encoder']` and make ajax url to `url: '{{ url('client') }}' + '/' + $('.id_search').val(),` . Change the data to `data: {keyword: $('.searchbar').val()},` . try this out

Comment: Done. But still got an 500 internal server error. Is my code in my controller is correct

Comment: check which url the form posts into and if the url is correct try dumping the request from your controller to see if it fixes your problem. I think it should be `return view(` instead of `echo`

Comment: @Paudel I already tried to var_dump it or use dd but still got an 500 internal server error. I already included the csrf protection from the ajax but still can't find light.

Comment: What's the error? Check you laravel and php logs.

Comment: @Bryan I have a wrong spelling in my controller of sample description manage to fix it. But now I don't have any errors. I tried to use vardump or dd but didn't work.

Comment: when I tried to dd the client reques object in the else statement i got an 500 internal server with no log. Weird. Maybe I should create a separate method with returning it as an array?

Comment: What happens when you open the URL in the browser (without AJAX)?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I got the right response with keyword or without that means my controller and route is correct right?

Comment: So it seems. Does your JS script use the correct URL?

Comment: Did you looked for errors inside `storage/logs/laravel.log`? Also, in your `.env` there is a `APP_DEBUG=true`?

Comment: Is it solved? I suspect `csrf_token` too. What do you see in your Network console?

Comment: I believe you have route overlapping, move your resource to the first line and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

In your  in blade file, the head section:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

csrf_token headers missing from your aJax. Replace with this:

```
 $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              type:"GET",
    headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
              url: '{{ url('encoder/client') }}' + '/' + $('.id_search').val(),
              data: {text: $('.searchbar').val()},
              success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
              }
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post is missing a clear question. I don't understand exactly what your specific problem is, but there is something that pops-up from your code:

```
url: '{{ url('encoder/client') }}' + '/' + $('.id_search').val(),
```

If your JavaScript is being loaded from an external file, url() method will not be accessible in the JavaScript and your code should report an error in your Developer Tools' console (you should see something like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"). If this is your case, replace

```
url: '{{ url('encoder/client') }}' + '/' + $('.id_search').val(),
```

with:

```
url: 'encoder/client/' + $('.id_search').val(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had the pleasure to try out the `Route::resource` even tho I feel I should have by now.

If you're looking for a different approach, you can do something among the lines:

1. Specify the HTTP Verb on the route and point to a controller's method

.

```
Route::get('show', 'ClientController@show/{id}');
//On the post, the standard is to send the id within the body but you can play {id} on the url if that's your plan
Route::post('show', 'ClientController@show');
```

You can build the whole application using only POST if you want it to, but I find using standards makes things more readable like reading a book (GET some client and PUT some client translates into get information of a client and put information of a client into the application)

> https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

2. You can and should return a view and not echoing it out (even if you can manage to access the view with it), and follow SOLID's principle whenever possible

> https://hackernoon.com/solid-principles-made-easy-67b1246bcdf

3. I'm not sure about this `findWithoutFail($id)`, assuming an $id gets passed by that doesn't exist, what is it supposed to do? Woudln't it be better to do a FindOrFail or validate it?

To help with your debugging, since its aparently without errors:
csrf token is required to be sent, as it's laravel protection against CSRF. If you wish to not use it, check the link below

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf

use `dd` to view the output of your queries, is it returning the expected result?
are you receiving the view as expected?
Try returning the data only (without the view) and console log the output

Edit: Post your status code 500 if you can't figure it out so we can help

Comment: I tried to dd the queries but I received an 500 internal server with no error logs which is weird. Should I create a separate method that will not point to any pages. The method will just return an array or json and get that json and display it on the foreach? But how?

Comment: place the application in debug mode https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration    and you should see the error

Comment: I turned it to true bit still not giving me logs about the error.

Comment: May I suggest you install Postman and test it there? It must print out an error, either in the logs or the message that comes along status code 500 (if it's in debug mode)

Comment: I get the correct response in POSTMAN, even if I typed the url in the browser without ajax. It returns the expected outputs.

Comment: If it returns the expected outputs...then where is the 500 code?

Comment: idk. It really drives me crazy this all the time. So the controller and the route code is correct. Maybe it's in the script of my ajax? But by default in my app.blade.php the ajaxSetup headers has already the csrf token.

Comment: Status code 500 means its an error on your backend code. If it's not 500, it's not the route's or controller's fault. IF you get the expected results from postman, your backend code is CORRECT.

Answer (score 0):

In the blade file setup the URL and get the URL from Blade or your Jquery code

Using the blade syntax in javascript is not the proper way.
Also check for the token in the request otherwise you can ignore the token for this route

```
<input type="hidden" id="show_url" value="{{ action('ClientController@show') }}">


var showURL = $("#show_url").val();
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type:"GET",
    url: showURL+'/'+$('.id_search').val(),
    data: {text: $('.searchbar').val()},
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned and gone in to detail regarding, it seems that you are missing the CSRF token in your request. Some have suggested to add the token to the request but might I suggest a better approach to save you the hassle in the future of having to worry about it.

1. In your blade layout template define in the `head` of your HTML a meta tag which references your CSRF token:

   ```
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   ```
2. Define a global JavaScript file which you will include in your page before you include any of your other JavaScript files.
3. Add to that global file the following code:

   ```
   $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
   });
   ```

Now, that has setup a rule that every AJAX request should include the aforementioned CSRF token in the header of your request.

However, an Internal Server Error implies that the error is taking place elsewhere, therefore I would suggest that you direct your attention to `storage/logs/laravel.log` and see if the error has been logged in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

Without the output of your `larvel.log` it's really just speculation on what exactly the issue is. However, there are a couple potential issues I am seeing:

**Change return data type**

Your ajax request is explicitly asking for `json` as set with the `dataType` property. You could try changing your return in the controller to something like this:

```
return json_encode([
    'data' => view()->make('encoder-dashboard.client.show', 
        compact('client_requests'))
    ->with('client', $client)
    ->render();
]);
```

Or update your dataType in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    ....
});
```

**Check if $client is empty**

in your controller you are loading your `$client` by using `findWithoutFail` and then immediately calling `$client->id` in the `if/else` block:

```
if (!$keyword) {
    $client_requests = AnalysisRequest::where('client_id', $client->id)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
} else {
    ...
}
```

If `$client` is empty, then that would cause an error. Instead, move your empty check before the `if/else` block:

```
if (empty($client)) {
    Flash::error('Client not found');

    return redirect(route('encoder.client.index'));
}

if (!$keyword) {
  ...
}
```

**Verify relations exists before chaining properties**

In your `request.blade.php`, you are trying to get properties of your relations without checking if they are present. This would cause a crash if they didn't exist. Instead, check that are not empty first:

```
@if (!empty($request->service))
    @if (!$request->service->isEmpty())
        <br>
        Service Requested: <b>{{ $request->service->description }}</b>
    @endif
@endif
```